# How to merge/combine 2 json arrays

Tags: c#, json, string, merge, arrays

So I have 2 json arrays as string in the below variables. They both have the header "invoices" and I would like to merge the two together so there is only 1 header and 4 items inside.

currently have:

```
var info1 = {"invoices":[{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/1","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/1"},{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/2","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/2"}]}

var info2 = {"invoices":[{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/3","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/3"},{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/4","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/4"}]}
```

Desired outcome:

```
var info3 = {"invoices":[{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/1","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/1"},{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/2","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/2"},{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/3","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/3"},{"url":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/invoices/4","contact":"https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts/4"}]}
```

Is there any functions that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to deserialize them to 2 instances of the same class, add the array items together, and then serialize the object back to string.

```
Info info1 = // deserialize info1
Info info2 = // deserialize info2

info1.Invoices.AddRange(info2.Invoices);

string json = // serialize info1
```

Types:

```
class Info
{
    List<Invoice> Invoices;
}

class Invoice
{
    string URL;
    string Contact;
}
```

Comment: How would i serialize the two objects together?

Comment: Solved it Thanks a lot :)